# Pass relatedTo value from Apex Code to VF Email template

Tags: email-template, singleemailmessage

I have a VF email template where the recipientType is contact and the relatedTo is case. I'm creating a singleeEmailMessage from Apex Code and I want to use above email template. I know I can set the contact record via `mail.setTargetObjectId(contact.Id)`. But is there any way that I can relate the Case record so that I can use that value in email template like `{!relatedTo.casenumber}`

Here is my template

```html
    <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Subject" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Case">
        <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
            <html>
                <head>
                  <STYLE type="text/css">
                      body {font-family: arial; color: #000;}
                  </STYLE>
                </head>
                <body contenteditable="true">
                    
                    <apex:image id="dme_logo" value="sample" />
                    
                    <br/>
                    <p style="color: #000;">Dear {!recipient.Name}</p>
                    
                    <p style="color: #000;">Reference number {!relatedTo.casenumber} </p>              
                    <p style="color: #000;">Thanks,<br/>
                    USER
                    </p>
                    
                </body>
            </html>
        </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
    </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

And the Apex code

```java
    EmailTemplate template = new EmailTemplate();
    template = [Select id, name from EmailTemplate where name = :EMAIL_TEMPLATE];
                
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setTemplateID(template.Id); 
    mail.setTargetObjectId(con.Id);
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
    //mail.setWhatId('5007A000003xd2K');    
    mail.setBccSender(false);
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
                
    mails.add(mail);
    system.debug('MAIL::'+mail);
    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
```

Comment: What is wrong with **setWhatId**?

Comment: It gives me System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: [] when I use a Case record

Comment: on which line are you getting the error, setting **whatId** should not be an issue though.

Comment: Messaging.sendEmail(mails); line 
Here is the debug point before this line:
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[getBccAddresses=null;getCcAddresses=null;getCharset=null;getEntityAttachments=null;getFileAttachments=null;getHtmlBody=null;getInReplyTo=null;getOptOutPolicy=SEND;getOrgWideEmailAddressId=null;getPlainTextBody=null;getReferences=null;getTargetObjectId=0037A00000LAdS7QAL;getTemplateId=00X7A000000QsZFUA0;getToAddresses=null;getWhatId=5007A000003xd2KQAQ;isTreatBodiesAsTemplate=false;isTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient=true;isUserMail=false;]

Comment: Code works well for system admin. I send it from a community user. But the access was given to necessary fields. Not sure why?